# How to resolve a package conflict when the problematic pkg is loaded by the class

Tags: warnings, l3doc

Code excerpt:

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{fvextra}
```

Symptom:

> Package fvextra Warning: csquotes should be loaded after fvextra, to
>   avoid a wa rning from the lineno package on input line 37

Diagnosis:

`l3doc` loads `csquotes` (section 5.5 of the doc)

Question:

Can anything be done about it?

Comment: You can use `\RequirePackage` (instead of `\usepackage`) before `\documentclass`.

Comment: In fact I had seen it, but read it too fast. Thx.